# run laravel 5 custom command on openshift

Tags: php, cron, laravel-5, openshift, openshift-cartridge

Anyone knows how to add laravel's custom command as cron job? Thanks in advance

Below is my script located at `.openshift/cron/minutely/robot.sh`

```
#! /bin/bash
php $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR/artisan robot:donate run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script works now. Cron wasn't running, so i have to start it manually.